# jquery on() and off() dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

first i register an event

```
$(document).on('change',"*[dependent-group]", function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        debugger;
        if ($(this).val()) {
            obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
        } else {
            obj.resetLists($(this));
        }
    });
```

then i turn it off with

```
 $(document).off('change',"*[dependent-group]");
```

The problem is that i attach the event again, it doesnt fire.

Answer (score 0):

Is `$(document).on('change',"*[dependent-group]")` how you "attach the event again"? If, yes, it doesn't reattach the first handler. You have to pass the handler.

```
function handler(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    debugger;
    if ($(this).val()) {
        obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
    } else {
        obj.resetLists($(this));
    }
}

$(document).on('change',"*[dependent-group]", handler); 
$(document).off('change',"*[dependent-group]", handler);
$(document).on('change',"*[dependent-group]", handler);
```

Note that you can also define a switch variable instead of using `off` and reattaching the handler.

```
var run = true;
function handler(e) {
    if (!run) return;
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    debugger;
    if ($(this).val()) {
        obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
    } else {
        obj.resetLists($(this));
    }
}

$(document).on('change',"*[dependent-group]", handler); 
// ...
run = false;
// ...
run = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn it on:

```
$(document).find("*[dependent-group]").change( function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        debugger;
        if ($(this).val()) {
            obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
        } else {
            obj.resetLists($(this));
        }
    });
```

To turn it off:

```
$(document).find("*[dependent-group]").off('change')
```

if you want you can belt and braces:

```
$(document).find("*[dependent-group]").off('change').change( function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        debugger;
        if ($(this).val()) {
            obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
        } else {
            obj.resetLists($(this));
        }
    });
```